# $R$-minimal elements and R-first elements.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a book on axiomatic set theory and the book says that all $R$-first elements of a set are also $R$-minimal elements, but there are cases where $R$-minimal elements are not $R$-first elements. Could someone provide an example of this?

Comment: Can you define R-first?

Answer (score 0):

If $R=\{(x,z), (y,z)\}$ is a relation on a set with three elements $\{x,y,z\}$, then $x$ and $y$ are both $R$-minimal but neither is $R$-least.